# Connection refused to host: 10.144.16.123 - where does this IP come from?

Tags: java, localhost, rmi, host

When I run service launcher in Eclipse for a web application I get the following error msg:

```
Connection refused to host: 10.144.16.123; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

I am asking myself where the host 10.144.16.123 comes from or where it is configured. When I check the configured program arguments in the launcher file it looks like this:

```
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROGRAM_ARGUMENTS" value="-d ${workspace_loc:project-backend}/custom/properties -r 1199 -c rmi://localhost:1199/ConfigService"/>
```

There, I can find localhost. Any idea how to check where  10.144.16.123 comes from?

Comment: also when I search in my whole project for 10.144.16.123, I cannot find it

Comment: How is localhost defined in /etc/hosts?

Comment: @user16632363 it is windows system

Comment: in  %windir%\system32\drivers\etc it looks like there are no configurations. everything there is commented out

Comment: Have you set up a proxy? `10.x.y.z` IPs are private IPs available only in your network.

Comment: This is item A.1 in the RMI FAQ linked from the RMI Home Page.